# Авторизация клиента на сервере

Tags: c#, active-directory

Задача такая: пользователь Иванов на своем доменном компьютере заходит на клиент который подключается к серверу. Задача сервера понять что подключился именно Иванов, а не кто то другой. Подскажите стандартные решения от Microsoft.

Comment: Что такое "заходит на клиент"? Клиент - это программа на c#, которую запускает пользователь? Что такое "сервер", к которому подключается программа? Это WCF сервис?

Comment: @AK да клиент и сервер на c#.  Реализация самая простая . Собственно интересует как безопасно и неопровержимо передать данные о пользователе AD

Comment: Что такое "клиент" и что такое "сервер"? Что-то готовое? Какой-то самопальный протокол? В случае WCF того же [уже есть готовые средства от майкрософт работать в домене](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-windows-authentication), в своём протоколе вам нужно [на клиенте определять залогиненного пользователя](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1240373/5752652) и передавать его creadentials.

Comment: @AK вот меня и интересуют готовые средства, сейчас посмотрю